# How to compile libs3 on Windows with MinGW when the code is not portable or not 32 bit friendly?

Tags: c, gcc, amazon-s3, makefile, mingw

We are having a series of problems when trying to compile libs3 (http://libs3.ischo.com.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html) on a Windows system using MinGW.

Seems that the code is not portable or not 32 bit friendly. I stumbled upon this error : http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/bugs/1315/ . It seems that we would have to dig into the libs3 code and fix it to compile with MingW. Not sure if there is a version of MingW that avoids this or solves this (it seems that this behaviour is by design by the MingW team).

We tried to fix the code issues with libs3 but in vain. Fixing one part, something else pops up (couldn'd find some libs even if they were there etc..).

In particular, the following MinGW Makefile code:
    # libs3 library targets

```
LIBS3_SHARED = $(BUILD)/bin/libs3.dll
LIBS3_STATIC = $(BUILD)/lib/libs3.a

.PHONY: libs3
libs3: $(LIBS3_SHARED) $(BUILD)/lib/libs3.a

LIBS3_SOURCES := src/acl.c src/bucket.c src/error_parser.c src/general.c \
                 src/object.c src/request.c src/request_context.c \
                 src/response_headers_handler.c src/service_access_logging.c \
                 src/service.c src/simplexml.c src/util.c src/mingw_functions.c

$(LIBS3_SHARED): $(LIBS3_SOURCES:src/%.c=$(BUILD)/obj/%.o)
    $(QUIET_ECHO) $@: Building dynamic library
    - @ mkdir $(subst /,\,$(dir $@)) 2>&1 | echo >nul
    $(VERBOSE_SHOW) gcc -shared -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) -lws2_32

$(LIBS3_STATIC): $(LIBS3_SHARED)
    $(QUIET_ECHO) $@: Building static library
    - @ mkdir $(subst /,\,$(dir $@)) 2>&1 | echo >nul
    $(VERBOSE_SHOW) dlltool --def mswin\libs3.def --dllname $(subst /,\,$<) \
            --output-lib $(subst /,\,$@)
```

gives:

C:>mingw32-make -f D:\libs3-2.0\libs3-2.0\GNUmakefile.mingw install
mingw32-make: *** No rule to make target 'build/obj/acl.o', needed by 'build/bin/libs3.dll'.  Stop.